# build a new array of hash from multiple array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following three array of hashes.

```
customer_mapping = [
      {:customer_id=>"a", :customer_order_id=>"g1"},
      {:customer_id=>"b", :customer_order_id=>"g2"},
      {:customer_id=>"c", :customer_order_id=>"g3"},
      {:customer_id=>"d", :customer_order_id=>"g4"},
      {:customer_id=>"e", :customer_order_id=>"g5"}
    ]

customer_with_products = [
      {:customer_order_id=>"g1", :product_order_id=>"a1"},
      {:customer_order_id=>"g2", :product_order_id=>"a2"},
      {:customer_order_id=>"g3", :product_order_id=>"a3"},
      {:customer_order_id=>"g4", :product_order_id=>"a4"},
      {:customer_order_id=>"g5", :product_order_id=>"a5"}
    ]

product_mapping = [
    {:product_id=>"j", :product_order_id=>"a1"},
    {:product_id=>"k", :product_order_id=>"a2"},
    {:product_id=>"l", :product_order_id=>"a3"}
  ]
```

What i want is a new hash with only customer_id and product_id

```
{:product_id=>"j", :customer_id=>"a"},
{:product_id=>"k", :customer_id=>"b"},
{:product_id=>"l", :customer_id=>"c"}
```

I tried to loop over product_mapping and select the customer_order_id that match product_order_id in customer_with_products and then thought of looping over customer_mapping  but not able to get desired output from the first step.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
def merge_by(a,b, key)
  (a+b).group_by { |h| h[key] }
       .each_value.map { |arr| arr.inject(:merge) }
end

merge_by(
  merge_by(customer_mapping, customer_with_products, :customer_order_id),
  product_mapping,
  :product_order_id
).select { |h| h[:product_id] }.map { |h| h.slice(:product_id, :customer_id) }

#=>[{:product_id=>"j", :customer_id=>"a"},
#   {:product_id=>"k", :customer_id=>"b"},
#   {:product_id=>"l", :customer_id=>"c"}]
```

Definitely not the cleanest solution, if your initial arrays come from SQL queries, I think those queries could be modified to aggregate your data properly.

```
merge_by(customer_mapping, customer_with_products, :customer_order_id)
# => [{:customer_id=>"a", :customer_order_id=>"g1", :product_order_id=>"a1"},
#     {:customer_id=>"b", :customer_order_id=>"g2", :product_order_id=>"a2"},
#     {:customer_id=>"c", :customer_order_id=>"g3", :product_order_id=>"a3"},
#     {:customer_id=>"d", :customer_order_id=>"g4", :product_order_id=>"a4"},
#     {:customer_id=>"e", :customer_order_id=>"g5", :product_order_id=>"a5"}]
```

Then merge it similarly with your last array and cleanup the result selecting only the elements for which `:product_id` was found, slicing wanted keys.

Alternatively, a much more readable solution, depending on your array sizes might be slower as it keeps iterating over the hashes:

```
product_mapping.map do |hc| 
  b_match = customer_with_products.detect { |hb| hb[:product_order_id] == hc[:product_order_id] }
  a_match = customer_mapping.detect { |ha| ha[:customer_order_id] == b_match[:customer_order_id] }
  [hc, a_match, b_match].inject(:merge)
end.map { |h| h.slice(:product_id, :customer_id) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your handling of the problem the solution would be the following:

```
result_hash_array = product_mapping.map do |product_mapping_entry|
        customer_receipt = customer_with_products.find do |customer_with_products_entry|
            product_mapping_entry[:product_order_id] == customer_with_products_entry[:product_order_id]
        end
        customer_id = customer_mapping.find do |customer_mapping_entry|
            customer_receipt[:customer_order_id] == customer_mapping_entry[:customer_order_id]
        end[:customer_id]
        {product_id: product_mapping_entry[:product_id], customer_id: customer_id}
end
```

Output

```
results_hash_array => [{:product_id=>"j", :customer_id=>"a"},
                       {:product_id=>"k", :customer_id=>"b"},
                       {:product_id=>"l", :customer_id=>"c"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option, starting from `customer_mapping`, one liner (but quite wide):

```
customer_mapping.map { |e| {customer_id: e[:customer_id], product_id: (product_mapping.detect { |k| k[:product_order_id] == (customer_with_products.detect{ |h| h[:customer_order_id] == e[:customer_order_id] } || {} )[:product_order_id] } || {} )[:product_id]  } }

#=> [{:customer_id=>"a", :product_id=>"j"},
#    {:customer_id=>"b", :product_id=>"k"},
#    {:customer_id=>"c", :product_id=>"l"},
#    {:customer_id=>"d", :product_id=>nil},
#    {:customer_id=>"e", :product_id=>nil}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cust_order_id_to_cust_id =
  customer_mapping.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    h[g[:customer_order_id]] = g[:customer_id]
  end
  #=> {"g1"=>"a", "g2"=>"b", "g3"=>"c", "g4"=>"d", "g5"=>"e"}

prod_order_id_to_cust_order_id =
  customer_with_products.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    h[g[:product_order_id]] = g[:customer_order_id]
  end
  #=> {"a1"=>"g1", "a2"=>"g2", "a3"=>"g3", "a4"=>"g4", "a5"=>"g5"}

product_mapping.map do |h|
  { product_id: h[:product_id], customer_id: 
    cust_order_id_to_cust_id[prod_order_id_to_cust_order_id[h[:product_order_id]]] }
end
  #=> [{:product_id=>"j", :customer_id=>"a"},
  #    {:product_id=>"k", :customer_id=>"b"},
  #    {:product_id=>"l", :customer_id=>"c"}]
```

This formulation is particularly easy to test. (It's so straightforward that no debugging was needed).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended to rather take a longer but more readable solution which you also understand in some months from now by looking at it. Use full names for the hash keys instead of hiding them behind `k, v` for more complexe lookups (maybe its just my personal preference).

I would suggest somethink like:

```
result = product_mapping.map do |mapping|
  customer_id = customer_mapping.find do |hash|
    hash[:customer_order_id] == customer_with_products.find do |hash|
      hash[:product_order_id] == mapping[:product_order_id]
    end[:customer_order_id]
  end[:customer_id]

  { product_id: mapping[:product_id], customer_id: customer_id }
end
```